# Remove \x from Cstring

Tags: c++, mfc

Have Byte* which have assigned to Cstring. So Cstring has hex data which is format \xData\xData.
I want to remove \x from the Cstring.
Have tried remove function but didn't worked. Can anyone suggest how to remove \x.

Comment: The \x escape is a way to represent non-printable control characters in a source constant. The actual Cstring variable contains a sequence of characters, each of which may or may not be printable. What's the real problem you are facing?

Comment: Cstring has values \xData, I want only Data part how to get that?

Comment: Please show an example of what you have and what you want.

Comment: What I have Cstring data =L"\x15\x16" What I want is  Cstring data = L"15 16"

Comment: So strip out all "\\x" from the string.You got to use `\\` to replace a `\` in a string.

Comment: Can you please share sample?

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question asked (although it's most likely not asking about the actual problem). You can easily replace any sequence in a `CString` with another sequence by calling [CString::Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#replace):

```cpp
CStringW transform(CStringW source)
{
    source.Replace(L"\\x", L" ");
    return source.Trim();
}
```

This converts a source string by replacing all occurrences of the character sequence `\x` with a space character, and then removes all leading and trailing whitespace characters. This implements the behavior asked for in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59499118/remove-x-from-cstring#comment105171712_59499118).